# How can I configure sudo to prompt for password and show the executed command?

Tags: 12.04, security, sudo

The title says it all. How can I configure `sudo` to prompt for password **and** show the executed command?

**Rationale:** if something gets aliased in the shell or I end up executing a function `sudo` instead of the program, I would still like to see the *actual* `sudo` (i.e. `/usr/bin/sudo` on Ubuntu) is going to execute before I do it. This is mostly for security reasons, i.e. I would configure this only for certain types of impersonation via `sudo`.

**Bonus points:** if this can be configured, is it also possible to use it with `NOPASSWD:` inside `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: It appears that the default action is to write the command to /var/log/auth.log. So you could write a bash function to parse the last sudo command by your UID. Downside is that you have to be a member of the adm group to view the auth.log file. Probably an enhancement request to the package maintainer.